# Fulltext results and wrongs results

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have a Full Index Catalog on the `Article` table define like this :

```sql
create fulltext catalog [Article_Catalog]
go

create fulltext index on [Article] (ArticleId, ArticleIdTrimed, Designation, FlatVehicles, FlatCategories, FlatCriterias) key index [Article_id] on [Article_Catalog] with change_tracking = manual
go

alter fulltext index on [Article] start full population
```

here are samples data :

[image]

I want to search the `ArticleId` `022.465` but I don't get any results when I do :

```sql
    -- Query 
    Declare @q as varchar(50) = '022.4'

    declare @q2 varchar(50)
    set @q2 = isnull(@q, '')
    declare @ft varchar(50) 
    set @ft = '"' + @q2 + '"'

    
    select
        a.DataSupplierId,
        a.SupplierId,
        a.ArticleId
    from
        containstable(article, (
        ArticleId, 
        ArticleIdTrimed
        ), @ft) ftx
        inner join article a on a.id = ftx.[key]
    order by
        ftx.[rank] desc
```

But, If I search this string, it's working :

`Declare    @q as varchar(50) = '022.465'`

It's working to with this :

`Declare    @q as varchar(50) = '022465'`

And I don't really doesn't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to make a prefixed search, appending `*` to your search criteria should provide you with the desired result.